# Collecting and combining data from iterative DFS on read-only trees

Tags: algorithms, trees, stacks

I am iterating over a tree through an API. This API provides a list of nodes sorted in post order DFS. I need to gather data for each node in the tree, combine that data with the parent's data (according to some heuristic not just a simple arithmetic accumulation). Another way to look at this, is that each node in the tree gathers data about its children and combines it to make its own data. Its parent, in turn, will use this data and combine it with its children.

There is no way to annotate the tree with the intermediate data. (No write permissions) Somehow, I need to associate each node of the tree with some data. One approach would be to use a map of some sort. The issue is that these N nodes do not have ids from 0 to N, so the map could introduce a O(Nlog(N)) complexity in an algorithm that should just be O(N).

Intuitively and by running a few examples, I can up with the pseudo code below.

```
StackOfData stack 
for each node in post ordered list
  data=initialize()   
  # Sibling order does not matter, 
  # all we care is popping the stack once for each child   
  for each child of node
    childData = stack.pop()
    data = combine(data,childData)   
  end

  mydata = node.extractData()   
  data = combine(data, mydata)   
  stack.push(data)
end
```

I am not so much looking for alternate ways of solving this problem. I am solely trying here to fill an academic void.

My question is :
Is there some theoretical proof to substantiate the above pseudo-code?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: 1. Why do you think a map would add $O(N \log N)$ complexity?  2. Are you talking about a hash map or a binary tree map?  A hash map will have better asymptotic efficiency (assuming a sufficiently good hash function), if that's what you care about.  3. How *are* nodes in the API's tree identified, if not by ids from $0$ to $N$?

Comment: Nodes can be identified by name or by pointer.

Comment: OK, you've answered one of my three questions.  What about the other 2?  (And please edit the question to incorporate these clarifications into the question -- the site design doesn't communicate this very clearly, but comments are intended to help you improve your question -- people shouldn't have to read the comments to understand your question.)

Comment: Your revised question asks whether your pseudo code is correct and whether it can be proven correct. 1. What have you tried? Have you tried proving it?  What techniques have you tried?  How far did you get, and where did you get stuck?  Have you tried it on some examples?  Have you tried formulating invariants and proving them?  We expect you to make a serious effort before asking here.  2. I'm afraid "is my pseudocode correct?" might not be a great fit for this site.  This is not a code review site.  Answers will be only "yes" or "no", which are not likely to help others in the future.

Comment: If it's correct, there is a proof, yes. What have you tried, what arguments of correctness do you think you can solidify?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a "shadow tree": a tree *you* build up, where each node of your node has a pointer to the corresponding node in the API's tree.  Basically, you do a deep copy of the API's tree.  Now you'll have write permission to your copy, so you can now augment/annotate each node with any additional information you want.  At this point you can do the linear-time bottom-up traversal to annotate all the nodes and aggregate the data.

The total running time will be linear in the size of the original tree ($O(N)$, not $O(N \log N)$).

Comment: I agree that this would work and it is conceptually very simple and therefore would have a good chance to be accepted by my peers. I was hoping to come up with a slick solution that would mimic the behavior of a recursive traversal by introducing a stack. This is not as straightforward however and was looking for some theoretical basis for it. The only references I found regarding non-recursive traversals is that they use a stack  in a while loop (that's tree traversal 101). I was trying to take this one step further and also use a stack for propagating data up.

Comment: @Renaud, this meets all of your technical requirements that were stated in your question.  If you had additional requirements that are not stated in the question, please edit the question to include them.  [Simple is good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).  "Slick" isn't a technical requirement.  If your colleagues object that this isn't "slick" enough, you can remind them of the following principle (sometimes attributed to Einstein): "Make things as simple as possible, but not simpler."  Finally, my solution *does* use a stack (to do the deep copy), if that was somehow relevant.

Comment: I realize now that I did not even ask a question. I have corrected that. Sorry for misleading you. I know what you are saying about keeping it simple but please bear with me here as I am really trying to stay away from the solution space and go into the more academic aspect of things.